# Not working imacros.js file

Tags: imacros

Script not going to URL'S from CSV file, what i'm doing wrong? Script not giving any errors.

```
 var macro;
    macro =  "CODE:";
    macro +=  "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE Facebook_Groups.csv" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1000" + "\n";
    macro += "SET !LOOP 1" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "URL GOTO='{{!COL1}}'" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:'img sp_sn-egcmZHgp sx_3e65cc'" + "\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var macro;
    macro =  "CODE:";
    macro +=  "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE Facebook_Groups.csv" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1000" + "\n";
    macro += "SET !LOOP 1" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "URL GOTO='{{!COL1}}'" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:img<sp>sp_sn-egcmZHgp<sp>sx_3e65cc" + "\n"; 


iimPlay(macro)
```

Comment: @ macroscripts yes thank's, one more question, it give's me an error when macros takes link to fb group from csv file, macros adds http:// before link  www.https.com//www.facebook.com/groups/213027422151936/?ref=bookmarks%20%27   in iim format everything works fine

Comment: Place csv file in datasource folder.